# Maybe you just need another perspective, Who am I posing as?

Tags: riddle

Where the ice meets the flesh

And the time comes to an Halt

Lost in the heart of men

Tarnished by my creation

---

Don't pay attention to the present

It's just a show

Same happens with my child

Never to be the same

Ending the Riddle I am

You might need another view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is

> Walter Elias "Walt" Disney

- As the title suggest, see the first letters of each line.

Where the ice meets the flesh

And the time comes to an Halt

Lost in the heart of men

Tarnished by my creation

---

Don't pay attention to the present

It's just a show

> Walt Disney is a name

Same happens with my child

Never to be the same

> first child/pregnancy of her wife ended in miscarriage

Ending the Riddle I am

You might need another view

> see first letter of each line and read it downwards

Comment: The riddle itself was mostly referring to Walt Disney's Disney going from 'the funland' to the currently allegedly "slave-working" company. However, as the riddle itself stated, It's just a show, and the puzzle itself was in thinking slightly outside the box (by looking at the first letter of each sentence)